# Function was partially completed

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

when you call function from another function, the calling function is paused in partially completed state and my computer use data structure stack. what is type stack uses my computer??

I expect it to be used (array stack or linked stack) or what type call stack

Comment: That depends on the programming language. Usually, the stack is array-based for performance reasons, and either fixed size (hence why you get "stack overflow" if your recursion is too deep) or dynamically grown.

Answer (score 0):

The stack that stores partially executed functions is the *call stack*.  It's like an array stack, but more primitive.  It's really just a fixed region of memory or address space, that is used starting at one end (usually the highest address) and growing toward the other.  A program can put whatever it wants on the call stack, and will use it as temporary storage for any type of data.

Your computer architecture determines what direction the stack grows.  Your CPU supports machine code instructions to call and return from from functions, and it has two internal registers called the "stack pointer" (SP) and the "instruction pointer" (IP).  The instruction pointer points to the next instruction that the CPU will execute.

When it executes a function call, the CPU does something like:

1. decrement SP;
2. copy the address from IP into the memory that SP points to; and
3. set IP to the address of the function being called.

When it returns from a function, it does something like:

1. read an address from the memory that the SP points to, and set IP to that address; then
2. increment SP.

It is these two CPU instructions that determine which way the stack grows -- calling a function decrements SP and stores the return address on the stack.  Return takes that address off the stack.  In this architecture, the stack therefore grows downward.

In modern desktop computers that have "virtual memory", each thread gets a fixed amount of address space to use as a call stack (1MB or so).  This doesn't actually *consume* memory, though, until it is used.  Address space is divided into *pages* (usually 4kb), and when a program tries to store something on a stack page for the first time, a page of physical memory is requested from the operating system and mapped to the address in the stack.